# Send 2D array via signal/slot in Qt

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I'm trying to send a 2D array via signal from a worker thread to GUI thread. But it's not working. What is wrong with this:
Definition of signal:

```
void parametersUpdated(double parameters[][100]);
```

emitting signal:

```
emit parametersUpdated(_parameters);
```

Signal/Slot connection:

```
connect(sender, SIGNAL(parametersUpdated(tdouble[][100])),
        receiver,SLOT(update(tdouble[][100])));
```

Comment: Wrap the 2d array in a struct and send it.

Comment: or use `QList<QList<double>>` to send it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution myself:
Instead of using array in Signal/Slot, I've sent (void*) and used this cast:

```
double (*array)[100] = static_cast<double (*)[100]>(voidStarObj);
```